# Ember can't find my template when using the renderTemplate hook

Tags: ember.js

I can’t figure out why Ember can’t find and render the template specified in my `renderTemplate` hook override. I have the following route configuration as per `router.js`:

```
  this.route('posts', function() {
   this.route('history', function() {
    this.route('new', { path: '/new/:id'});
   });
  });
```

I’m also making use of my history `index` route. Therefore, my `history.hbs`  is just an outlet, and all my templating for this route is actually housed in `index.hbs`. This way, I can render my `new.hbs` template on its own page.

In `new.hbs`, I’d like to render an outlet, in addition to some other content. To handle this, I attempted to override the `renderTemplate` hook in `routes/new.js`, like this:

```
  renderTemplate() {
   this.render('posts/history/test', {
    into: 'new',
    outlet: 'test',
   });
  }
```

I created the new template under `templates/posts/history:`test.hbs`. File structure for my templates folder looks like this:

`templates > posts > history > new.hbs, test.hbs`

Finally, in `new.hbs`, I added my outlet for this new template:

`{{outlet 'test'}}`

When I navigate to my `new` route, I get the following error: 
`Assertion Failed: You attempted to render into ’new' but it was not found`. Anyone know how I can get past this?

Comment: You can try ` into: 'posts/history/new'`

Comment: sadly doesn't work

Comment: Try with • instead of /

Comment: still nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only render into an ancestor route.

Comment: I want to accept this answer, but I can't find any documentation to assert this! Specifically looking here: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Route/methods/renderTemplate?anchor=renderTemplate